# Does PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS permission effect auto update?

Tags: android, android-permissions, user-permissions

I am adding PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS permission to my app. Since this is a special permission that the user needs to grant from a special settings page, I would not expect it to appear in the Google Play permission list when they install the app - and thus I expect it not to enforce manual update for my app. Will it enforce manual update for my app or it will allow auto update for existing users?

Comment: why do you think dangerous permissions are not listed in google play?

Comment: @TimCastelijns, because these are the runtime permissions. Anyhow I'm not much worried whether is listed on Google Play permission or not, my only concern is, will this permission block users from auto update? We are supporting minimum API version 16 and this permission was added in API 21.

Comment: runtime permissions also have to be listed in the manifest

Comment: ok got it Thanks!! Just curiosity, If my app has 10 features out of that only 1 feature needs this permission, so user will opt for that feature by allowing this permission at runtime. What is the point to ask them while installing or upgrading the app.
Anyhow App can't use this feature until and unless user allow this at runtime.

Comment: they are not asked - only informed. The asking is done by you, at some point in the app

Comment: To make it clear, permissions listed on google play are from the manifest file, doesn't matter if you really use it or not. When you use some runtime permission, then you need to check if it was already granted, if not, you have to ask for it. You should do this at the point when the app needs the permission, for example when your app has to save some file to the storage when some save button is pressed, check/ask for the permission only when the user presses the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a permission will cause, that users will have to update the app manually. 
All the permissions, which are in your manifest file are listed on Google Play. 
Doesn't matter if it's runtime permission or not.